# How i can save my string in multiple lines?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi i need help with that my code its:

```
keyword  = input("")


engine = Google()
results = engine.search("site:anonfile.com " + str(keyword))
links = results.links()

file1 = open("results.txt","w")
file1.writelines(links)
file1.close()

print(links)
```

The results are saving like that

`https://cdn-32.anonfile.com/B6Cau9Fbn7/6e7bf257-1576485241/x3152 Spotify Premium Account by The Jester.txthttps://cdn-04.anonfile.com/S4u7K9f1b7/ceaa1f97-1539376777/Spotify.txt`

I want it to be saved as follows but I don't know how to do it :(

```
https://cdn-32.anonfile.com/B6Cau9Fbn7/6e7bf257-1576485241/x3152 Spotify Premium Account by The Jester.txt
https://cdn-04.anonfile.com/S4u7K9f1b7/ceaa1f97-1539376777/Spotify.txt
```

I use google translator, sorry if you don't understand what i say.

Comment: Try adding for loop to it, so you can append ```\n``` at the end of each string. Then write it to a file. All should be in new lines.  Also, it is better to use with open statment.

Comment: Can you show what inside Google() function?

Comment: What is ```Google()```? Where does it come from?

Comment: @Jakub you can write the code? pls thanks!!